# Optional Named Capture group with suffix

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a specification of the command

`RENAME_SECTION file::section [new_file::]new_section`

`file`, `section` and `new_section` are mandatory, `new_file` is optional.

Than means that all next expressions will match:

```
RENAME_SECTION io.cfg::BUS1 io.cfg::BUS3
RENAME_SECTION io.cfg::BUS2       io_new.cfg::BUS2
RENAME_SECTION io.cfg::VID VID1
```

I try to get all provided parameters with Python `re.search(pattern, config_line)` using the pattern

```
(?P<command>RENAME_SECTION\s)\s*(?P<file>\S+)::(?P<section>.*)\s+(?P<target_file>\S*)[::]?(?P<target_section>.*)
```

This pattern match two first cases, but not the third one, the reason is absents of last `::`.

How can I bundle `::` with `target_file` named capture group?

Comment: `file::` is not optional: its the source of section. If `new_file` is not specified the target file is the same as a source file.

Comment: I see you said that explicitly in the question. Sorry for the trouble. I'll delete this comment when I figure you've seen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this regex with an optional match and anchors:

```
^(?P<command>RENAME_SECTION)\s+(?P<file>\S+?)::(?P<section>\S+)\s+(?:(?P<target_file>\S+?)::)?(?P<target_section>.+)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XoqMol/2)

`(?:(?P<target_file>\S+?)::)?` is an optional non-capturing group that makes matching `target_file` and trailing `::` *optional*.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider a pattern like

```
(?P<command>RENAME_SECTION)\s+(?P<file>\S+)::(?P<section>\S+)\s+(?:(?P<target_file>[^\s:]+)::)?(?P<target_section>\S+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XA4hQg/2). If you plan to match a whole string with the pattern, add `^` at the start and `$` at the end.

**Details**

- `(?P<command>RENAME_SECTION)` - a `RENAME_SECTION` string
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?P<file>\S+)` - 1+ non-whitespaces
- `::` - a `::` substring
- `(?P<section>\S+)` - 1+ non-whitespaces
- `\s+`  - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?:(?P<target_file>[^\s:]+)::)?` - an optional group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `[^\s:]+` - 1+ chars other than whitespace and `:` chars
  - `::` - a `::` substring
- `(?P<target_section>\S+)` - 1+ non-whitespaces.

Comment: Thank you @wiktor stribiżew , but for this expression in last case `VID1` is identified as `target_file` and not `target_section`